# iOS : Autofill Login / Password in Facebook login page loaded in UIWebView

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, uiwebview

I have been handed an app which has a UIWebView which loads Facebook login page ( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login/#webview ). I want to ensure that the user doesnt have to put the values everytime.

Since I am not generating the page (Facebook is), the only way I can think of is as mentioned in [How do I autofill username and password in UIWebView iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086470/how-do-i-autofill-username-and-password-in-uiwebview-ios-app) . This appears to be a hack, and will fail if Facebook changes the page.

Is there any better solution that uses the FB login page embedded in UIWebView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of October 2nd, apps must not use their own webviews for log in, and according to the breaking change policy, will have 90 days to comply. (Using the webview supplied by the SDK is still OK).

See https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

You definitely should NOT autofill username/password in a webview.

Comment: In that case, which of the options provided on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login/ are available to us from the list : 1. Facebook App; 2. Native iOS 6; 3. Facebook App Web;
4. Mobile Safari; 5. Embedded WebView; 6. Flow and Control ... and which of these would not require the user to fill-in his login credentials more than once

Comment: If you're using the SDK as supplied by Facebook, it automatically caches the access token, so there's no need to re-login at all. You only need to authorize once (or when updating permissions).